# How to load string to a pandas df with columns names

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following string that I read from file:

```
 `something` `something_else` /dev.py
 `something2` `something_else2` /tasks.py
```

I want to create a df that looks like:

```
       1        2              3
`something` `something_else` /dev.py
`something2` `something_else2` /tasks.py
```

I tried:

```
f = open("te.txt", "r")
string = f.read()
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(' ') for x in string.split('\n')])
```

but this doesn't work as expected.
It gives me df of 5 columns. It should be only 3 columns with 2 rows.

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: @jtlz2 see edit. I simplified the question

Comment: just replace `split(' ')` by `split()`.  for no depends on the number of spaces.

Comment: @djangoliv Thank you! I knew it's something simple! Please post answer so I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `read_csv` with the following options:

```
df = pd.read_csv('te.txt', sep='\s+', engine='python',
                 header=None, skipinitialspace=True)
print(df)

# Output:
              0                  1          2
0   `something`   `something_else`    /dev.py
1  `something2`  `something_else2`  /tasks.py
```